# Xcode - How to add a Resources Target

Tags: xcode, resources, target

I am creating a framework similar to one that was created by somebody else.

Here is what the original framework has for TARGETS:

[image]

Here is what my new framework has for TARGETS:

[image]

Here is an image of what a Resources Target contains:

[image]

---

```
                       **I know how to add a Target.**
```

---

I'm trying to add a **Resources** Target and I cannot figure out which template to use.  Or perhaps there is a different way to add a Resources Target.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate that I can't give somebody the points for this but (after much research and no bites) I finally found a [site](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/05/resource-bundles/) with the answer.

Here is a picture.  I hope this information helps somebody else in the future.

[image]